# How to fix getStaticProps type when using InferGetStaticPropsType in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I don't know why there was an error in the post props.
The error description is `Property 'body' does not exist on type 'never'`.

[image]

`InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticPaths>` Can there be an error even if I specify the type with?

```
interface IParams {
  params: {
    slug: string;
  };
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: allPosts.map((p) => ({ params: { slug: p._raw.flattenedPath } })),
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: IParams) {
  const post: Post = allPosts.find(
    (post) => post._raw.flattenedPath === params.slug
  ) as Post;

  console.log(post);
  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
}

export default Detail;
```

when I check `console.log(post)`, Its structure is as follows.

```js
{
  title: 'good ! ',
  date: '2022-08-10T00:00:00.000Z',
  description: 'this is description',
  tags: 'Typescript',
  body: {
    raw: '## hello world',
    code: '' },
  _id: 'second.mdx',
  _raw: {
    sourceFilePath: 'second.mdx',
    sourceFileName: 'second.mdx',
    sourceFileDir: '.',
    contentType: 'mdx',
    flattenedPath: 'second'
  },
  type: 'Post'
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const Detail = (post: InferGet.....` ?

Comment: Seems like the type broke down. You might want to search their GitHub issues and if you don't find anything there you can open your own.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, when using `getStaticProps` with parameters, you have to type the function with `GetStaticProps` in order to `InferGetStaticPropsType` to pick up the correct props type.

```js
import type { GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType } from 'next';

type PropsType = { 
    post: Post 
};
type ParamsType = ParsedUrlQuery & { 
    params: { slug: string } 
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PropsType, ParamsType> = async ({ params }) => {
    const post: Post = allPosts.find(
        (post) => post._raw.flattenedPath === params.slug
    ) as Post;

    return {
        props: {
            post
        }
    };
}

const Detail = ({ post }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
    //            ^ Should pick up `Post` type instead of `never`
    return (
        <></>
    );
};
```